# Excels INDEX with MATCH for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am experimenting with excel's functions. Say I have the following example values
Column
A1 - "Andrew"
B1 - "Morton"
B2 - "Andrew"
A2 - "Morton"
A3 - "2"

Why is my formula not printing the output 2?

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$3,
MATCH(A1, ($A$1=$B$2:$B$2) * ($B$1 = $A$2:$A$2), 0))
```

The following prints the correct output 2 with single criteria.

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$3,
MATCH(A1,$B$2:$B$2,0),1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the example is confusing, provide a dummy data set example and the expected results.

Comment: What is your lookup array in the first formula? `($H$10=$H$11:$H$11) * ($I$10 = $I$11:$I$11)` doesn't seem right.

Comment: The idea is that INDEX will obtain the number 2 if MATCH matches both the 'Andrew's and the 'Morton's

Comment: So say if you were looking up a value for a person, but the set of persons could have similar first names or surnames, you would check both criteria to ensure you are getting the correct data for that person

Comment: There isn't a problem when Im comparing A1 to B2. But expanding it to compare A1 to B2 and B1 to A2, is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These type of formulas don't work well with single cell ranges, as per your example.

Lets assume first names in `A2:A10` and  last names in `B2:B10` - if you want to find the row which matches **both** names and return the corresponding value from `C2:C10` you can use this "array formula":

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$10="Andrew")*($B$2:$B$10="Morton"),0))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or you can add an extra `INDEX` function to avoid array entry

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$10="Andrew")*($B$2:$B$10="Morton"),0),0))`

Comment: Perfect, including the extra INDEX solved the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to perform for either Andrew OR Morton?